# Proving Density of Subset of Hilbert Space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Suppose we have a subspace, $M$, of Hilbert space $H$. Prove the first statement implies the second statement:

1) If $<f,g> = 0$ for any $g\in M$, then $f=0$ in $H$.

2) $M$ is dense in $H$.

I am thinking that we need to use the following theorem: If $\{g_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ is orthonormal set in $H$, then the following are equivalent:

a) If $<f,g_{\alpha}> = 0$ for any $g_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha \in A$, then $f=0$ in $H$

b) Every $f\in H$ can be written as convergent linear combination of countably many $g_{\alpha}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need to use the theorem you listed, we can also use other theorems. One theorem that gives a particularly direct proof is

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T \subset H$ a closed subspace. Then we have the decomposition $H = T \oplus T^\perp$.

Which space to use for $T$ is hopefully not hard to find out.

Comment: Thus, setting $T=M$, we get that $M^{\perp} = {0}$. Thus $H=M$? But I really only want density...in fact, I don't want $H=M$.

Comment: In the theorem, $T$ is a closed subspace. We don't assume that $M$ is closed. But what does $M$ being dense mean, by definition?

Comment: @DanielFischer what if T is just subspace. To write in that decomposition you need T to be closed.

Comment: @Toeplitz In the situation of the question, we let $T = \overline{M}$. We note that by continuity of the inner product, we have $M^{\perp} = T^{\perp}$, so $M\text{ is dense} \iff T = H \iff T^{\perp} = \{0\} \iff M^{\perp} = \{0\}$. The equivalence of the outermost propositions includes the assertion of the question.